# Why my mp4 video does not play on mobile?

Tags: javascript, video, mp4

I am trying to make mp4 video autoplay to work on my website on mobile. I have applied same technique to do it on both of my websites and it is not working only on one of them which is very strange! I feel like I am running out of ideas!

Here is the first website where it does not work: https://wearepharos.com/    pw:pharos123
It is hosted on Shopify.

Here is another website where I do same thing but somehow it is working on mobile:
https://sebastianwalach.com/

I am using this script to add playsinline to the video which does the job on the second website:

```js
<script> 
    setTimeout(
        function(){ 
            var mobilevideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video"); 
            var i; 
            for (i = 0; i < mobilevideo.length; i++) { 
                mobilevideo[i].setAttribute("playsinline", "");
            } 
        }, 
    3000);
</script>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Mobile devices often block autoplaying video, especially if there has been no user interaction on the site. The only thing you can do is add user interaction that causes the video to play.

Comment: @Kokodoko how do you explain that the video is working on the second website. I am even using the same jquery library to load it. It's called vide.js. I think there has to be very specific reason why it is not working.

Comment: In my own tests some sites automatically got  “whitelisted“ by the browser. The browser remembers that the user once allowed autoplay video. But you should bear in mind that for new users who visit your site for the first time, autoplayng video will probably be blocked - at least that’s my experience.

Answer (score 0):

One reason may be that your mp4 video is using the 'high' h.264 profile.

H.264 has different profiles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Profiles) and not all devices support all profiles.

For example the Android baseline support does not include 'High' profile, although some Android devices may support it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Here is a output from ffprobe for the mp4 version of your video:

```js
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/.../Downloads/VICIS_2_-_HIGHLIGHTS (1).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-11-11T00:35:32.000000Z
    encoder         : Google
  Duration: 00:00:49.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1955 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1824 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-11T00:35:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/10/2019.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-11T00:35:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/10/2019.
```

Comment: I have tried to change the format to webm but I am getting the same result. Thank you for you answer though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just to be sure, I have used the same video on both sites. The problem still remains. It looks like it must be something else.

Comment: @SebastianWalach - can you share the devices it works on and the ones it does not?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a correct explanation for that issue but instead I applied a "hack" jQuery fix that is actually working just fine. I am posting it as maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
function playVid() { 
  $('video').get(0).play();
} 
          setTimeout(playVid, 3000);
```